# Is the use of "it" to refer to a customer correct in this sentence? Shouldn't it be "he"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

An application has the customer registry and when i click on it, there is a button "Turn inactive", when i click it the following message is displayed:

> "This customer has outstanding transactions. **It** can't be made inactive."

Is the use of "it" correct because the customer is being referred as an entity? Wasn't suppose to be "he"?

Comment: If we added "he", "she", or "they" in place of "it", I would wonder "How do you make a person (he/she) inactive?" I think "it" is appropriate because it refers to the object in the application, and not to the person that object represents.

Comment: "Their account cannot be made inactive". You could use "His ..." or "Her ..." if you know them to be male or female, respectively.

Comment: It may be more clear if you see it thusly: This customer('s account) has outstanding transactions. It can't be made inactive.

Comment: It's not clear to me.  *What* can't be made inactive?  The customer?  The transactions?  Something else?  I would rephrase it like AdrianHHH says: *The customer's account can't be made inactive.*

Comment: @stangdon I added some context to the message appearence in the question.

Comment: Thanks, @GabrielAbel.  I would not refer to a customer as "it", because a customer is usually a person, or at least treated like one, and we don't refer to people as "it".  At the same time, "he" implies a certain gender, which isn't really appropriate if the customer is female or an entire company.  Again, I would avoid the entire issue by saying "the account" or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can 'it' be used to refer to a person?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105993/can-it-be-used-to-refer-to-a-person)

Comment: I think that this is not a dupe because the *customer* is not being referred to as "it".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I don't believe the it here refers to the customer, but rather to their account.  More context is needed to be certain, but I don't believe one can make a person "inactive" in the way implied here.

Comment: Added more information about where the message is displayed. The customer is just a registration indeed. My question is if it's correct to refer to him as or if it's better to refer to the person the registration represents.

Comment: The question is a bit abstract at this point. If you are talking about a real, live person, you absolutely use "he", "she", or "they" as it may apply. But the application is a digital representation. In OOP there is probably a "Customer" class/object which is being flagged as inactive, and that can be referred to as "it". And you're not making the actual customer inactive, you're flagging their account as inactive. @GabrielAbel

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use "it" for a customer, I'd say you should provide what you want to say. You can always use he/she

Comment: See the edit to the question.